# How do I create a bash script to open some of my apps?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

apologies for such simple questions. I am currently learning backend development for which every time I open my PC, I need to open 3 apps. I have tried to make a bash script which could open all of those app using a single exe file.

This is what I have tried:

```
#! /bin/sh
code .
```

This script opens VS Code. But the problem is that I can't specify the project directory. Also using this I cannot open the other two apps which are Postman and Mongodb compass.

Please Help me to make a script which I can use to open these apps automatically.

Comment: "I cannot open the other two apps" -- why not? what happens?

Comment: Did you check documentation for command line arguments for each of those apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other programs are likely waiting for the first to terminate. Try

```
#! /bin/sh
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
```

The ampersands allow the script to execute the next command without the current one terminating. As for your other issue, I recommend doing what the comments say and checking the documentation for running the programs from the command line.